# Regular expression to delete the whole line include the end of line

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to delete all the commented lines in a powershell script using another powershell script. I expected this to be very easy, but apparently it is not. Here are the things I tried, and obviously didn't work:

```
(Get-Content commented.ps1) -replace '^#.*$', '' | Set-Content uncommented.ps1
(Get-Content commented.ps1) -replace '#.*$', '' | Set-Content uncommented.ps1
```

These worked, but the end of line is still there, so now I have some empty lines instead of the comments, which is not what I want.

```
(Get-Content commented.ps1) -replace '#.*\r\n', '' | Set-Content uncommented.ps1
(Get-Content commented.ps1) -replace '^#.*\r\n$', '' | Set-Content uncommented.ps1
(Get-Content commented.ps1) -replace '#.*\r\n$', '' | Set-Content uncommented.ps1
```

I also tried to write just `\n`, even though I'm sure my file is CRLF. And I also tried to put `\n` or `\r\n` at the beginning. These did not work at all, but they also didn't error.

Test files:

commented.ps1 :

```
#This is a comment
$var = 'this is a variable'
# This is another comment
$var2 = 'this is another variable'
```

expected uncommented.ps1 :

```
$var = 'this is a variable'
$var2 = 'this is another variable'
```

I simply don't get it why `\r\n` does not match end of line. Any help is highly appreciated. I guess the question is:

How to match the end of the line successfully in powershell using `Get-Content -replace`?

Comment: Maybe copy whole file line by line with asserting first sign with # ? If there is one, simply skip the line and proceed to the next one.

Comment: \r\n is only used on Windows default file encoding. If you created your file on linux for example, you wont have the \r every time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `-replace` you can use simple `Where-Object` to filter lines without the comment sign (`#`), the regex as well is pretty simple, `^#` means match any `#` character at the start of the line, see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

```
(Get-Content commented.ps1) | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch '^#'} | Set-Content uncommented.ps1
```

Comment: Yes, I also thought about that. Good one!

Comment: this works, so I guess it is the right answer, but can you give some explanations of why? That would make it a lot better answer. If you also happen to know why \r\n didn't work, it would be perfect.

Comment: the regex I got, the -notmatch, I also got. I guess ? is a shortcut to Where-Object and I guess the $_ is a placeholder for the content. Right?

Comment: Do you happen to know why \r\n does not work? by the way, stackoverflow prevents me to accept your answer as an answer for a couple more minutes.

Comment: @Andrei `\r\n` not work because there is no `\r\n` in strings returned by `Get-Content`, unless you use `-Raw`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thank you! Now I get it. Get-Content sets an array with the content of each line.